# Unable to install plugins form jenkins browser?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install  cloud foundry plugin from Jenkins browser and am seeing the below error. (I have selected the option "download and install after restart" option). I dont want to install plugins manually as i need to install many in future.Can someone help me?

error:

---

```
Checking internet connectivity
Checking update center connectivity
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.testConnection(UpdateCenter.java:1240)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.checkUpdateCenter(UpdateCenter.java:1045)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$ConnectionCheckJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1461)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be behind a proxy. Have you configured it?
I had a similar Exception and it was resolved by configuring my proxy settings under Jenkins-> Manage Jenkins-> Manage Plugins-> Advanced tab.

Comment: I have configured it, I gave server name,port, i gave Jenkins username and pw and gave google.com as the test url, but am getting same error. I am unable to connect to internet from Jenkins server also.